# Mesh see-throught if look on some angles

Tags: rendering, mesh, import

So i made some mesh in quad draw in maya. And after import to Blender, when i look at some angles, it becomes see-through. I tried to recalculate normals but it fix nothing. It happens only in render view.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this being rendered in EEVEE?

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: Possible overlapping geometry - check for duplicated vertices or faces that overlap other faces. In Edit mode select all and ‘Merge by Distance’